# changing strokeRect colour on hover

Tags: javascript, html

so i'm playing around with HTML and JavaScript and i'm trying out the Canvas element.
so I made a simple strokeRect that acts as a button.
I want to make it so it changes the strokeRect colour when i hover over it
how would i do this?
Here is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>UNNAMED</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="secret" width="360px" height="30px"></canvas>
<canvas id="drawing" onClick="secret()" width="102px" height="42px">Your browser doesn't support the canvas element</canvas>
<script src="jsfil.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my JavaScript code

```
var cSecret = document.getElementById("secret").getContext("2d");
var cRect = document.getElementById("drawing").getContext("2d");
var cText = document.getElementById("drawing").getContext("2d");
cText.font="18px Times New Roman";
cText.fillText("Click me",18,26);
cRect.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
cRect.strokeRect(1, 1 , 100, 40);
var secretFound = false;
function secret() {
if(secretFound == false)
{
    secretFound = true;
    cSecret.font="24px Times New Roman";
    cSecret.fillText("Congratulations, you found a secret",1,20);
   }    
}
```

And here is my css code

```
#copyright{
position: absolute;
top: 92%;   
}
#drawing{
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
left: 50px;
border: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: blue; 
}
#drawing:hover{
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
left:   50px;
border: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: red;
}
#secret{
    position: absolute;
}
```

I want to change the strokeStyle when I hover over the rectangle.
i've tried using CSS but that only creates a new border.
One way I thought of doing it is checking the cursor position
if the cursor is in this area it would change colour but it feels like there should be an easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canvas does not work like that. If you want to change something, you have to redraw. You can take a look at SVG, that allows to modify things with Css.

Comment: Checked it out seems to be much easier to work with aswell thanks!